# Active Pivot Table Name

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a worksheet with multiple Pivot Tables.  All the pivot tables are formatted the same way.

How do I move multiple fields to values using VBA for active pivot table in the worksheet?

I tried recording a macro to move the fields to values but end up having to manually change the pivot table name in the VBA code when I want to use the macro for another pivot table.  I'd like to avoid having to go in and change the pivot table name manually.

You can see in the screen capture, I manually drag the "Value" in the field list to the "VALUES" area for each of the pivot tables.

It's a repetitive task I'd like to automate using VBA but each of the pivot tables have unique names.

[Excel Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYNxB.jpg)

Comment: Please explain "move fields to values", it doesn't really make sense...

Comment: What do you define as the "active" pivot table ?

Comment: Essentially, I want to move the same fields for each pivot table over to the values area using VBA.  "Active" meaning the active cell within the pivot table.  In other words, I've clicked on a cell within the pivot table I want to use the macro for since there are multiple pivot tables on a single worksheet.

Comment: Ah, ok, now I understand. Thanks.

Comment: I'm very new to VBA and learning on the fly.   I believe I know how to move the fields over to the value area, but I do not know how to properly reference the pivot table name within VBA without going in and changing the name manually.

Comment: If all you want to change from one iteration to the next is the pivot table name, try writing it as a Sub, where you pass the pivot table name in as an argument, then use that argument (in place of the pivot table name) in all of the formatting code.  Then just call the sub for each pivot table you want to format.

Comment: I don't understand what it is you want to do. You want all the pivot-tables to be synchronized somehow? When you change something in one pivot, it should happen the same in the others (add column, remove a column, change order, change sorting, change filtering Etc..). Looks to me that it will be far easier to gather the data in one sheet adding a column with the "title" you have in column A, and then make one pivot of it all.

Answer (score 2):

See http://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/  for a good overview of how to address the various parts of a pivot table.

This should get you started:

```
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    
    Set pt = ActivePivotTable
    
    If pt Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "No Active pivot table"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Active = " & pt.Name
        'work on pt...
    End If

End Sub

'get the pivot table which contains the current selection
Function ActivePivotTable() As PivotTable
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        Debug.Print pt.Name, pt.TableRange2.Address
        If Not Intersect(Selection, pt.TableRange2) Is Nothing Then
            Set ActivePivotTable = pt
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next pt
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim...  It was enough to get me started indeed!

Comment: Nice solution Tim. May I have just one question? Inside the function you declared an "rv" Variant variable. Does it make anything or is it some leftover?

Comment: @MrZH6 - just a left-over.  I've edited to remove it.